# Help with Adr1ft for PS4?

Tags: adr1ft

I can't find where to go on the Internet in general for help with this, but we are playing Adr1ft for PS4 and the game keeps crashing while we grab for air.

Comment: Generally, we prefer questions to ask only one thing.  Try to narrow your question down to one specific problem.  If there's more than one thing you want to ask, ask another question!  We're not going to run out of those anytime soon. :P

Comment: Edited. Frankly, since there were 0 adr1ft questions/answers I figured I'd cover my bases, but the main metaproblem is that we don't know where to go for these questions where there are lots of people who can help.